# Supervisor - Running a python script PYTHONPATH issue

Tags: supervisord

I am using supervisor to run a python script:

```
[program:twitter_track]
autorestart = true
numprocs = 1
autostart = false
redirect_stderr = True
stopwaitsecs = 1
startsecs = 1
priority = 99
command = python /home/ubuntu/services/twitter.py track
startretries = 3
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/logs/twitter_track.log
```

But the process fails to start. Here is what the error log says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/services/twitter.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mymodule.twitter.stream import TwitterStream
ImportError: No module named mymodule.twitter.stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/services/twitter.py", line 6, in <module>
```

It seems that obtain mymodule, but if I run twitter.py on it's own, everything works fine, it only throws this error when I run it through supervisor.

I added mymodule to the PYTHONPATH in my ~/.profile file like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/lib
```

Is there any reason why the script would work when run through terminal but not when run through supervisor? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add the `PYTHONPATH` definition to the `environment` directive in the supervisord configuration file. It should go under your `[program:twitter_track]` section, like so:

```
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/lib/
```

This will ensure that that your python process sees the proper `PYTHONPATH` when supervisord starts it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the PYTHONPATH definition to the environment:

```
[program:twitter_track]
command = python /home/ubuntu/services/twitter.py track
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

@Darren Griffith give right solution. But if we see off docs
http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings -> environment
We wee, that it says

> A list of key/value pairs in the form KEY="val",KEY2="val2"

So you need use a quotes **""**

```
[program:twitter_track]
command = python /home/ubuntu/services/twitter.py track
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/ubuntu/lib"
```